# LeapMotion - GestureList is always empty. I want to recognize a gesture but i can't

Tags: java, netbeans, leap-motion

We are using JAVA and SDK 3.2.1(LeapMotion).

What I want to do is see if I can recognize one of their own gestures in Leap Motion. I have done the research and a lot of people used "this way"(i tried to reach there by doing something like in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Eli8OpYSaI), with no problems. But I have been trying to do it but the "GesturesList" (gestures) is always empty, so the code doesnt even enter the for loop, where is suppose to recognize the gestures. I can´t move on. Pls some recommendations.

[GestureList is always 0, so i cant even enter the for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjzmT.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUFkL.png)

Comment: Can you please add your code like what you have tried ?

Comment: @prasad its on the photos, the blue links. the last two lines of the question. i put a printscreen of the code and of the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gestures were deprecated in Orion (v3 and above), so if you're using one of the Orion versions of the Leap SDK then it won't work. You can still use the [v2 SDK](https://developer.leapmotion.com/sdk/v2) if you want to use these Gestures, otherwise you'll need to implement them yourself.